# Releasing ArcMap memory by removing *.sr.lock files from shapefiles

Tags: arcmap, c#, arcgis-10.4, memory, lock

Is there a method of removing *.sr.lock files from shapefiles to release memory consumption without closing out of an ArcMap application?  I am attempting to run code that will cycle through 200+ folders filled with shapefiles and perform various actions on them.  I close the current map document and open a new one after each folder.  However, this is causing ArcMap to build up memory and eventually crash after around 100 folders are processed.  A big part of this problem (I would suspect) is the existence of lock files on each shapefile that exists. I have tried using a ComReleaser and Marshal.ReleaseComObject, but nothing seems to get rid of these lock files aside from completely closing out of ArcMap, which is not an option.  Is this just the way ArcMap handles shapefiles?

The following is a small portion of my code that creates the lock files:

```
// Loop through the selected shapefiles and load them into the map

pGxObjects.Reset();

while ((pGxDataset = (IGxDataset)pGxObjects.Next()) != null)
{

    pProDlg.Description = "Loading selected shapefile(s)...";
    pStepPro.Message = pGxDataset.DatasetName.Name;
                    
    IFeatureLayer pFeatLayer = new FeatureLayer();
    pFeatLayer.FeatureClass = (IFeatureClass)pGxDataset.Dataset;
    pFeatLayer.Name = pFeatLayer.FeatureClass.AliasName;

    pMxDoc.FocusMap.AddLayer(pFeatLayer);

    // Check if the cancel button was pressed. If so, then stop the process.
    boolCont = pTrkCan.Continue();
    if (!boolCont)
    {
        pProDlg.HideDialog();
        return null;
    }

    pStepPro.Step();
}
```

Comment: Lock files are created so that ArcMap *doesn't* need to use memory or file I/O channels to hold locks.  Removing the lockfiles isn't likely to save memory, but it is likely to corrupt the application or cause a crash.

Comment: Thank you Vince for your response.  If the lock files are not causing a problem with the memory, is there anything that can be done to increase the amount of memory that is used?  The ArcMap application consistently crashes after around 100 folders are processed and about 430 MB of memory.  It doesn't seem like that is much memory consumption for crashing ArcMap.

Comment: It's rare that there's a request to use *more* memory.  Massive memory use for something other than large Python dictionaries is generally something to be *avoided*. 430Mb is more than half of the reliable memory usage of a 32-bit process.  Memory use is an indication of a defect in your code, but it is likely not the defect itself, and it is certainly not the solution.